# Not able to send the message using Azure service bus

Tags: java, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Dotnet samples (send/receive) are working fine.
From java I am not able to send the message but receiving messages are working fine.

```
private boolean connectServer()
{
    try {
        if (null != senderClient) return true;
        senderClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)
                .sender()
                .queueName(queueName)
                .buildAsyncClient();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
}



public boolean sendMessage(String message) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        connectServer();
        senderClient.sendMessage(new ServiceBusMessage(BinaryData.fromString(message)));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any error. In `Azure portal --> Overview`. I can see multiple **incoming requests** but **incoming messages** are 0.

[image: Azure Portal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
ServiceBusSenderClient senderClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .sender()
                .queueName(queueName)
                .buildClient();

        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello world!");
        senderClient.sendMessage(message);
        System.out.println("Sent  messages to the queue: " + queueName);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Any idea why async is not working?

Comment: @Gentleman please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-messaging-servicebus/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/servicebus/SendMessageAsyncSample.java